# Breaking changes in Angular-CLI 1.0.0

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I updated my global Angular-CLI today to 1.0.0, and tried to run a project I've been working on, and I got this:

```
The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js:14:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/eject.js:10:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I decided that trying to upgrade my local version of Angular-CLI would fix this, but then I got a ton of errors from things that have apparently been broken by the new CLI version. Most of this is project specific:

```
ERROR in /Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/lib/layout/navbar/pg-dash-navbar.module.ts (3,10): Module '"/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/index"' has no exported member 'DropdownModule'.

ERROR in /Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/chart-test2/chart-test2-title-bottom/chart-test2-title-bottom.component.ts (3,10): Module '"/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/index"' has no exported member 'DropdownModule'.

ERROR in /Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/chart-test2/chart-test2.module.ts (7,10): Module '"/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/index"' has no exported member 'DropdownModule'.

ERROR in /Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/chart-test1/index.ts (1,15): Cannot find module './chart-test1-widget.component'.
/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/chart-test1/index.ts (2,15): Cannot find module './chart-test1-edit-widget.component'.

ERROR in /Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/chart-test2/index.ts (1,15): Cannot find module './chart-test2-widget.component'.
/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/chart-test2/index.ts (2,15): Cannot find module './chart-test2-edit-widget.component'.

ERROR in /Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/data-table1/index.ts (1,15): Cannot find module './data-table1-widget.component'.
/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/data-table1/index.ts (2,15): Cannot find module './data-table1-edit-widget.component'.

ERROR in /Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/map/index.ts (1,15): Cannot find module './map-widget.component'.
/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/map/index.ts (2,15): Cannot find module './map-edit-widget.component'.

ERROR in /Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/news/index.ts (1,15): Cannot find module './news-widget.component'.
/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/news/index.ts (2,15): Cannot find module './news-edit-widget.component'.

ERROR in ./src/demo-app/widgets/map/map-widget/leaflet@1.0.3.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/layers.png' in '/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/map/map-widget'
 @ ./src/demo-app/widgets/map/map-widget/leaflet@1.0.3.css 6:7520-7550
 @ ./src/demo-app/widgets/map/map-widget/map-widget.component.ts
 @ ./src/demo-app/widgets/map/map.module.ts
 @ ./src/demo-app/core/demo-core.module.ts
 @ ./src/demo-app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/demo-app/widgets/map/map-widget/leaflet@1.0.3.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/layers-2x.png' in '/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/map/map-widget'
 @ ./src/demo-app/widgets/map/map-widget/leaflet@1.0.3.css 6:7674-7707
 @ ./src/demo-app/widgets/map/map-widget/map-widget.component.ts
 @ ./src/demo-app/widgets/map/map.module.ts
 @ ./src/demo-app/core/demo-core.module.ts
 @ ./src/demo-app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/demo-app/widgets/map/map-widget/leaflet@1.0.3.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/marker-icon.png' in '/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/dashboard/src/demo-app/widgets/map/map-widget'
 @ ./src/demo-app/widgets/map/map-widget/leaflet@1.0.3.css 6:8648-8683
 @ ./src/demo-app/widgets/map/map-widget/map-widget.component.ts
 @ ./src/demo-app/widgets/map/map.module.ts
 @ ./src/demo-app/core/demo-core.module.ts
 @ ./src/demo-app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

I could have tried to fix the bugs, but then I wouldn't be sure if my colleagues would be able to run my project without upgrading as well. So I tried to revert to an older version via:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3
```

But then when I run any ng commands, I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'command'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:17:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

Going back to the most recent version of Angular-CLI fixes this, but then I'm back to that stack of errors with my project, where I'm not sure if the fixes will cause issues with older versions of Angular-CLI.

I'm really stuck here. Think I have to start all over maybe. Like uninstall Node? What should I do?

Comment: I guess you also have to revert the local Angular CLI: `rm -rf node_modules dist` `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3` `npm install` according to the update guide https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli . Even though you are not updating but downgrading, you should follow all the instructions.

Comment: What version of node/npm are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do the migration guide again [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update) and make sure you update your [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) to 6.9.0 or higher.